# CRM 2013 - create view for cases with closed activities

Tags: view, dynamics-crm-2013

I need to create a **view for cases** (incidents) in CRM 2013:

- **Show cases where all activities are closed or canceled**
- If there are open/scheduled activities, don't show this case in list

I did not manage to define this criteria by the filter criterias of the views.

I could write a plugin which counts open activities on every change of each activity. Is there a better way? Workflows?

Calculated and rollup fields don't exist in CRM 2013 yet, so they are not yet a solution.

Thanks for help and hints!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see plugin is the only appropriate way for you.